# How to convert an array into an Object property in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a complex object in a SPA javascript that I need to send to the Api using Ajax. One of the properties is an array and I'm trying to map an array to the id property before sending the data to the Api. Here's the code:

This is the class (the id is a string in the database):

```
var ContactList = {
     AcntNumber: 0,
     Contacts: [
       {
        id: "",
        name: ""
      }
   ]
}
```

Then in another file, I'm getting the values from a dropdown and creating an array contacts. I'm having hard time to assign the array to the id of the ContactList.Contacts.

```
           var users = [];
            var ContactList = Object.assign({}, ContactList);

            $('select#users').each(function () {
                Array.prototype.push.apply(users, $(this).val());
            });
                                                                      
            ContactList.Contacts = Object.assign({}, users);

            ContactList.AcntNumber = $("#accNum").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` },
                async: false,
                url: URL,
                data: JSON.stringify(ContactList),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

I keep getting the following error:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.

Here's my Classes in the Api:

```
public class ContactList
{        
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public Accounts Account { get; set; }
}  

public class Contact
{        
    public string ID { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could use `map()` to build the array of `id` values, however I'm confused why you're trying to use `each()` to loop through `select#users`? Given that you're select an element by its `id` there should only ever be a single element in the DOM, so the loop is redundant. Is is a multiple select and you're instead trying to retrieve all selected values? Seeing the HTML of the relevant elements would help a lot here

Comment: You're sending a single value but attempting to deserialize an Enumerable. This: `var ContactList = Object.assign({}, ContactList);` creates a single Object. It appears you don't need that at all - just send the users array: `data: JSON.stringify(users),`

Comment: The object ContactList has an account name and a list of users so I can't just send the array by itself. The stored proc is expecting the account and the list of users. I'm getting the list of users from a multiselect dropdown.